# Cannot import local files in python debugger (vs code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am doing the following:

1. `mkdir folder_structure`
2. `mkdir folder_structure/utils`
3. `touch folder_structure/utils/tools.py`
4. `touch folder_structure/main.py`
5. Write in main.py:

```py
from folder_structure.utils.tools import dummy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dummy()
```

6. Write in tools.py:

```py
def dummy():
    print("Dummy")
```

7. `touch folder_structure/__init__.py`
8. `touch folder_structure/utils/__init__.py`
9. Run the vs code debugger

I'm getting:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'folder_structure'
  File "/Users/davidmasip/Documents/Others/python-scripts/folder_structure/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from folder_structure.utils.tools import dummy
```

I have the following in my launch.json:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I import a local module when using the debugger?

This works for me:

```bash
python -m folder_structure.main
```

Comment: are u missing `__init__.py` ?

Comment: adding inits in both folders I get the same:

Comment: `touch folder_structure/__init__.py`

Comment: `touch folder_structure/utils/__init__.py`

Comment: not sure, but I think u need to add `cwd` field in `configuration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the launch.json to this:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "folder_structure.main",
            "justMyCode": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"
            },
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        }
    ]
}
```

and debugging the module works.

Answer (score 0):

You need replace

```py
from folder_structure.utils.tools import dummy
```

With

```py
from utils.tools import dummy
```

Comment: This works, but I shouldn't need to change my code, that works just fine from the folder I run it in order to be able to debug it, right? In particular, if I keep running from the root folder after doing this, the code crashes